# Uploading multiple images with one input field

Tags: php, file-upload

i have created a photography website with an admin page that uploads photos to different categories in a mysql table. This much works, but i can only upload one file at a time and i'd like to be able to select multiple images.

Here's the form

```
<form action="index.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="myForm" id="myForm" method="post">

    <select name="category" id="category">
        <option value="Nature">Nature</option>
        <option value="People">People</option>
        <option value="Abstract">Abstract</option>
    </select>

    <input type="file" name="fileField" id="fileField" />

    <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Add Images" />

</form>
```

And here's the php for parsing the form

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

$category = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['category']);
// Add this product into the database now
$sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO images (category, date_added) 
    VALUES('$category',now())") or die (mysql_error());


 $pid = mysql_insert_id();
// Place image in the folder 
$newname = "$pid.jpg";
move_uploaded_file( $_FILES['fileField']['tmp_name'], "../photos/$newname");
header("location: thumbnail_generator.php"); 
exit();
}
```

I looked into the html5 file input method, and as far as i can tell, i can change the input as folllows:

```
<input type="file" name="fileField[]" id="fileField" multiple="multiple"/>
```

This allows me to select multiple files on the site, but i can't figure out how to implement this into my php. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are probably looking for something like [uploadify](http://www.uploadify.com/) or [swfupload](http://swfupload.org/) or [plupload](http://plupload.com/).

Comment: Personally I use SWFUpload, Uploadify actually uses SWFUpload so depending how good your JavaScript is, I'd go for Uploadify or SWFUpload.

Comment: broken link for swfupload

Answer (score 5):

```
<form method="post" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="500000">
Add Photos <input multiple="true" onchange="this.form.submit()" type="file" name="photos[]"/>

<input type="hidden" name="sendfiles" value="Send Files" />
</form>

    <?php
define ("MAX_SIZE","5000"); 
function getExtension($str)
{
         $i = strrpos($str,".");
         if (!$i) { return ""; }
         $l = strlen($str) - $i;
         $ext = substr($str,$i+1,$l);
         return $ext;
}

$errors=0;

if(isset($_POST['sendfiles'])) 
{
  $uploaddir = "files/"; //a directory inside
    foreach ($_FILES['photos']['name'] as $name => $value)
    {
        $filename = stripslashes($_FILES['photos']['name'][$name]);
     //get the extension of the file in a lower case format
          $extension = getExtension($filename);
         $extension = strtolower($extension);
        echo "\n This is the extension: ",$extension;
         if (($extension != "jpg") && ($extension != "jpeg") && ($extension != "png") && ($extension != "gif")) 
         {
        //print error message
        ?>
           <h4>Unknown extension!</h4>
          <?php
             $errors=1;
         }
        else
        {
            $size=filesize($_FILES['photos']['tmp_name'][$name]);
            if ($size > MAX_SIZE*1024)
            {
            ?>
               <h4>You have exceeded the size limit!</h4>
              <?php
                $errors=1;
            }
            $image_name=$filename.'.'.$extension;
            $newname="files/".$image_name;
            $copied = copy($_FILES['photos']['tmp_name'][$name], $newname);
            if (!$copied) 
            {
                ?>
                <h4>Copy unsuccessfull!</h4>
                <?php
                $errors=1;
            }

        }

    }
    //echo "Images uploaded successfully";
}
//mysql_close($dbhandle);
?>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this may theoretically answer the question, it would be preferable to include the explanation as well.

Comment: Whats the problm, I got **Warning: copy(): Filename cannot be empty** in `$copied = copy($_FILES['photos']['tmp_name'][$name], $newname);`

Answer (score 3):

It works as-if there were [multiple file fields<sup>*­Docs*</sup>](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.multiple.php), it's transparent to PHP. Here is some simple example code:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      <input type="file" name="fileField[]" id="fileField" multiple="multiple">
      <input type="text" name="test" value="test">
      <input type="submit" name="submit">
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
<?php
var_dump($_FILES, $_POST);
```

Store it on your host and request it. You can then play around with it, it will show you the structure of the `$_FILES` and `$_POST` array.

Example output:

```
array
  'fileField' => 
    array
      'name' => 
        array
          0 => string 'hakre-iterator-fun-cut-top.png' (length=30)
          1 => string 'hakre-iterator-fun-cut-middle.png' (length=33)
      'type' => 
        array
          0 => string 'image/png' (length=9)
          1 => string 'image/png' (length=9)
      'tmp_name' => 
        array
          0 => string '/tmp/php1A2.tmp' (length=15)
          1 => string '/tmp/php1A3.tmp' (length=15)
      'error' => 
        array
          0 => int 0
          1 => int 0
      'size' => 
        array
          0 => int 234001
          1 => int 213058
array
  'test' => string 'test' (length=4)
  'submit' => string 'Submit' (length=6)
```

See [*Uploading multiple files<sup>­Docs</sup>*](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.multiple.php).

Answer (score 1):

Simple! Just Add multiple="true" to your input tag.

```
<input name "example" type="file" multiple="true"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try out this.

http://www.uploadify.com/demos/

> Uploadify is a powerful and highly-customizable file upload script. Uploadify is easy to get up and running with
>   minimal effort and little coding knowledge.

Comment: That's more a comment than an answer.

Answer (score 0):

you will receive an array of images -> fileField[]. Just iterate through this array and add the images the same way you were adding them before. Also, I'd suggest using this, very nice script - http://valums.com/ajax-upload/

**EDIT:** Just don't forget to implement at least some security checks, like min and max upload size, file extensions and mime-type checking! Even if it's for the back-end, this could still lead to unpleasant events.

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't something like creating an array work too? So what he could do is

```
$images = array();
```

Then in his form just add a add to image list button? From there he just keep adding as many images as he wants and then just iterate over the array and add to the database?